# How do i implement a data filter?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I wrote some php where i output posts, title, images.
The three posts i have at the moment is added to 2 categories. So i have to category for the 3 posts. 
Now i want that, if a customer click on lets say one of the categories, i only want that post to show.

```
if ( ! empty( $image ) && ! is_wp_error() ) {
        ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="">
        <?php echo $text; ?>
        <?php echo $overskrift; ?>

        <?php
    }

    if ( ! empty( $text ) && ! is_wp_error() ) {

        echo $text;

    }

    if ( ! empty( $overskrift ) && ! is_wp_error() ) {

        echo $overskrift;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

**Code to show Category Tabs**

```
<ul class="filter-list list-inline nav nav-tabs" role="tablist"><li role="presentation" class="cat_li">
<a href="# Your Category slug 1" aria-controls="# Your Category slug 1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" title="# Your Category Name" data-placement="bottom" ><span>#Your Category Name</span></a>
<a href="# Your Category slug 2" aria-controls="# Your Category slug 2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" title="# Your Category Name" data-placement="bottom" ><span>#Your Category Name</span></a></li></ul>
```

**Here You need to add posts for particular category**

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="Your Category slug 1">Your Category posts</div>
<div class="tab-pane" id="Your Category slug 2">Your Category posts</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.tab-pane {
padding: 15px 0;
display: none;
```

}

**Note**
**You Need to Add Bootstrap for this functionality..**

**Please refer below link for the same**

[Reference Link](https://sen.world/map/#bs-example-navbar-collapse-4)